# Action bar icon app v7

Tags: android

How can I change programaticcaly android´s action bar´s icon with appcompat v7 on an ActionBarActivity? Thanks

```
ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

// set the icon
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.navbar_logo);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.drawable.navbar_logo);`

Or if you need the actionBar variable for other tasks as well

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.navbar_logo);
```